# how to split name in dataframe's column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'A-101': ['1','2','4'], 'B-102': 
['5','7','8'],'A-102': ['1','2','9']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

which is

```
   A-101    B-102   A-102
0   1        5      1
1   2        7      2
2   4        8      9
```

how to change above into the follow:

```
company  number   '0'  '1'   '2'
   A      101      1    2     4
   B      102      5    7     8
   A      102      1    2     9
```

Here I wan to split the column name `A-101`  into two columns and `transpose` the column into a row with name column name `'0', '1', '2'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `str.split()`:

```
(df.set_axis(df.columns.str.split('-',expand=True),axis=1)
.T
.rename_axis(['company','number'])
.reset_index())
```

or `pd.wide_to_long()`

```
(pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),
i = 'index',
j = 'number',
stubnames=list('AB'),
sep = '-',suffix=r'\d+')
.T
.stack()
.reset_index(level=1))
```

Output:

```
index  number  0  1  2
A         101  1  2  4
A         102  1  2  9
B         102  5  7  8
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

```
output = pd.DataFrame(columns=['company', 'number', '0', '1', '2'])

output['company'] = [col.split('-')[0] for col in df.columns]
output['number'] = [col.split('-')[1] for col in df.columns]
output['0'] = df.iloc[0].values
output['1'] = df.iloc[1].values
output['2'] = df.iloc[2].values
```